# Изменяющая рамка сайта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Привет, ребята. Я верстаю сайт по макету и как вы могли заметить, есть серая рамка, которая должна меняться в зависимости от размера окна браузера, так же как и на сайте http://sumka-opt.ru/. Так вот, как это сделать? Если, что сайт я делаю на opencart [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 2em);
  margin: 1em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: то есть, чтобы мне так сделать не реальном сайте, то мне нужно объединить после и перед тегами body добавить теги div?

Comment: Вам нужно положить сайт внутрь контейнера.

Answer (score 1):

На том сайте ширине страницы(основного контента) фиксирована. Там идет обертка .main-wrapper {width:1170px;}. При такой реализации достаточно на body{background-color:#ccc;} и оно автоматически будет заполнять края, НО если ширина меньше 1170px появится горизонтальный скролл.(можете проверить сами) Если это Вам подходит, то решение готово.